# Blender 2.78a sapling add-on vertical attraction

Tags: sapling-addon

When I learned Blender, was with the version 2.77 and in the sapling add-on was an option called vertical attraction that make the branches in shapes that looks like a tentacles, now in the latest version (2.78a) the option is gone, anybody knows where I can find it again?

Answer (score 1):

The sapling addon in 2.78 was mostly [rewritten by a new developer](https://developer.blender.org/T46559), vertical attraction would be an option that didn't get included with the new version.